# How to use library in Angular, `ng serve` and `ng build <library-name> --watch` will throw error

Tags: angular

My goal is to separate a feature into project. Possibly each feature should have its own package dependency. I am starting with the smallest one, a model.

The problem is that, when the models' library rebuild, the main application will throw a warning.

To build

```
npx @angular/cli@13 new angular-library-example
npx ng generate library models
```

To run

```
npx ng serve
npx ng build models --watch
```

The main application will throw

```
Error: src/app/shared/users/users.service.ts:3:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@@models' or its corresponding type declarations.

3 import { User } from '@@models';
```